# How to correctly set id limit in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a question about how to set an id field in mySql table.
This may seem basic for some of you but I cannot find the correct answer.

I have a pivot table with fields:

```
id          (int(11)) 
store_id    (int(11))
product_id  (int(11))
price       (decimal(10,2))
```

Every time the table is updated all the data is purged and new data is inserted, so the table never contains more than 20000 records, so not much.

However, I noticed that the id field (which is a primary key and is autoincremented) always assigns higher ids that the ones that were "freed" during deleting data.

I'm afraid at some point I will run out of numbers. Is int(11) enough? Should I set a different value? Or maybe will the numbering start from the top while I reach the limit?

Please advise. I cannot submit any code, since there is no coding involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table is not referenced with any other table then you can `Truncate table` instead of `delete` it. So when you insert the new data it will again start with 1

Comment: That totally solved my problem. Thank you kind sir. I will mark the answer as soon as the system allows me to do so.

Answer (score 1):

int(11) can be between -2147483648 and 2147483647 (Signed) or 4294967295 (Unsigned). So you dont need to worry about running out of numbers.

Comment: You are right, I just did the math based on your answer and it seems I can update data everyday for 588 years until I run out of numbers.